# Get backend field of inherited generic-collection class

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I want create a filterable list, but need the backend field of the items/collection in the parent collection class, so everything like e.g. Linq works, but still pases my sorting. There are no `get` and `set` to simplify this, are they ?

```
class FilterableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _baseCollection;
    private ObservableCollection<T> _filteredCollection;
}
```

Comment: `this` *is* the base collection, so its a little confusing to hold two collections inside a collection. If you want to do it like that, you may want to implement `CollectionBase`, not `ObservableCollection`. You access the base class methods by prefixing the call with `base.`Something.